# Change MySQL prices with just 1 input field based on a custom formula for each id?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with some prices in it:
[image]

But I want that I can give every id a formula like : `[thatnumber]` * or / or - or + . = `[AndShowThatPrice]`

So for a example:
I want just to type here a price: [image]

If I type 10 then I want that the formula for the `id=0` will be like:
10 *** 8** = 80 <<--- Update to that price in MySQL

And so I want to give each id a formula
So for `id=1` example:
10 **+ 140** = 150 <<--- Update to that price in MySQL

*** I just want to type the total price in one field, like : 10, then from that value the math will be made and the total price will updated in the database ***

Answer (score 0):

You would need at least one other field on the table that would contain your math for prices.  For instance a field called math that would be +140.  The you could do an update statement with one input box

Comment: But every id needs to have a different math for the prices! EG: We just only have 1 price like: 3000 and from that price the math has to be made for each ID

Comment: Exactly.  One field for every I'd with different math. Ie, id 1 would be +140. Id 2 would be /30,...

Comment: * I just want to type the total price in one field, like : 10, then from that value the math will be made and the total price will updated in the database *

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` statement in your update clause based on the id. It looks something like this:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET price = 
   CASE WHEN id = 0 THEN (10 * 8)
   WHEN id = 1 THEN (10 + 140) ELSE
   0 END;
```

You will have to determine a business rule to fall back on if the id isn't in any of your categories. In my example, I just set it to 0.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i make that work with only  1 input and a button? like : http://i.imgur.com/4fgwN32.png And where i have it will be calculated from the typed input like: 3000 ?

Comment: You can add a `WHERE` clause where you use the input as a parameter `WHERE id = @param` @SSD

Comment: You added `THEN ( 10 * 8)` <<- That is not good because i have to type the number value in a textfield so it should be somehting like this:  `THEN ( [inputvalue] * 8)`

Comment: `$strSQL = "UPDATE orders";
$strSQL = "SET prijs = ";
$strSQL = "   CASE WHEN id = 0 THEN (10 * 8)";
$strSQL = "   WHEN id = 1 THEN (10 + 140) ELSE";
$strSQL = "   0 END;";


$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
if($objQuery)
{
 echo "Save Done.";
 
}
else
{
 echo "Error Save [".$strSQL."]";
}
mysql_close($objConnect);` Is not working

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be:
    You have four possible operations and you can say that each operation
    have one id number, e.g:
    0 for +, 1 for -, 2 for * and 3 for / then use the module operator to
    determine which operator use, something like:

For example if you're using PDO.

... get the PDO conn

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase',      $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable');
    $stmt->execute();

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
        $operator = $row['id'] % 4;
        switch ($operator) {
            case 0:
                $newValue = $inputField + price;
                break;
            case 1:
                $newValue = $inputField - price;
                break;
            case 2:
                $newValue = $inputField * price;
                break;
            default:
                $newValue = $inputField / price;
       }
       $updateStmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE myTable set prijs = :pirjs WHERE id = :id');
       $updateStmt->execute(array('prijs' = $newValue, 'id' => $row['id']));$stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what is failing

Comment: I can not get this work connected with the database, do you maybe have a example for me, how i can implement that in the php page with the this form: http://i.imgur.com/4fgwN32.png Thanks!

Comment: thanks! Now i have this in my page, but i think something is wrong?: http://i.imgur.com/k9qCgho.png